# Linearization of an implicitly defined function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, approximation, implicit-differentiation

$f(x,y,z)=e^{xz}y^2+\sin(y)\cos(z)+x^2 z$

Find equation of tangent plane at $(0,\pi,0)$ and use it to approximate $f(0.1,\pi,0.1)$. Find equation of normal to tangent plane.

My attempt: I found that tangent plane is $(2\pi-1)(y-\pi)=0$ or $y=\pi$ (all partial derivatives except $y$ equal 0).

I don't know how to find linear approximation from it.
What is the equation for linear approximation?
Possibly it is $L(x,y,z)=f(0,\pi,0)+(2\pi-1)(y-\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an implicit function. An implicit function is like $0=e^{xz}y^2+\sin(y)\cos(z)+x^2 z$. Instead, your function is a 3D explicit function.

You are correct on your linear approximation $L(x,y,z)=f(0,\pi,0)+(2\pi-1)(y-\pi)$ and that is exactly the tangent plane $w=f(0,\pi,0)+(2\pi-1)(y-\pi)$.

Comment: Why tangent plane is $\omega=f(0,\pi,0)+(2\pi-1)(y-\pi)$? http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GradientVectorTangentPlane.aspx In the above link it is given without $f(0,\pi,0)$, just dot product of gradient on corresponding point.

Comment: @AndrewFount: This is what I mentioned as the beginning. You have an explicit function $f(x,y,z)=...$ instead of $k=......$. You might want to look at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx. This is the explicit function case but in $2$D.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.